# ParseInt Syntax

Tags: java, android, parsing, sdk, int

I'm having a problem with the `parseInt` method in Android sdk. So far I have one simple edit text and one button in my program. I now want to save the number in a new Variable in my program on button click, so what are the steps I need to take to do so?

So far my code looks like this:

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int val = Integer.parseInt(EditText.getText().toString());
    }
    // Perform action on click
});
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem. What do you want exactly ?

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your code snippiest,

You can initialize **EditText* variable like that

```
final EditText editText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int val = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
        }
            // Perform action on click
        }
```

Try to use above solution, I hope it will work

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save a variable accessible from all your app, you can use the shared preferences.

Example :

// To save your int

```
final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("App", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
final SharedPreferences.Editor sharedPreferencesEditor = sharedPreferences.edit();

final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int value = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());

        sharedPreferencesEditor.putInt("YourValue", value);
        sharedPreferencesEditor.commit();
    }
});
```

// To retreive your int

```
sharedPreferences.getInt("YourValue", 0);
```

Comment: Thank you, it's a little more complex than i need it rigt now but it solved the problem as well.